# css: how to access a value that is not used by an element?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV that gets its height from a CSS class in a separate stylesheet. But that height is sometimes changed in Javascript. Can I read the CSS height direct from the stylesheet without creating a new element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 var myDiv = $("#myId"); 
 alert('initial height from css is: ' + myDiv.css("height"));

 myDiv.css("height","50px");
 alert('height modified by js is: ' + myDiv.css("height"));

 // store modified height value
 var height = myDiv.css("height");

 // set height to an invalid value
 myDiv.css("height","");

 alert('height is now retrieved from css again: ' + myDiv.css("height"));

 // restore height value
 myDiv.css("height",height);
```

I created an example on jsfiddle.net, you can view it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/melih/9qqEG/1/).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you are creating a temporary element and then reading its properties - so reading direct from the stylesheet is not possible?

Comment: This example is not creating a new element; it first saves the calculated height value, resets the element's height style so that it takes the css value and restores the value to its value before modification. Why don't you want to create a new element? Because this solution will most probably cause some changes in the display during its execution which will not be good from user experience point of view.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating a new element because it felt inefficient to change the DOM when al I want to do is read a value from the stylesheet. But it looks like I'll have to. I can't just quickly resize the original element: it is a character in a game, and when its feet go off the screen I shrink the DIV, otherwise the page resizes and looks wrong.

Comment: I did not measure the performance of creating a new DOM element but my "instincts" tell me that creating a single div element with a single class won't cost much on client-side. But, of course, you might want to measure the performance and make sure it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's possible, provided that the height change is initiated by a known cause.

First, save the current inline height / class names. Then, reset the class / height property. Then, use the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) method to read the current height. Finally, restore the class/height properties. Let's assume that the class names don't have to be removed, because the height is only changed through setting the inline `height` property. Then:

```
function getCSSheight(elem) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
    return style.getPropertyValue("height"); //Returns 222px;
    // Optionally: Use parseFloat to convert the `22px` to `22`.
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to reset the height, even if for a fraction of a second? My DIV objects are near the bottom of a fixed size screen. I reduce their heights in order to avoid forcing a screen resize. Even a temporary resize to full height would cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot read any properties from CSS.

You can create some backend API that allow you change your CSS files directly from JavaScript, than you can change `height` in CSS file instead of applying `style` to an element.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, he's asking how to use JavaScript to read a style property as declared in the stylesheet, rather than an existing element's computed style which may have been changed by another script.

Comment: You mean server side? I'm creating a simple game that can has to run offline (people can either play online or buy the files and run it locally), so server code isn't an option.